# How to display table in onfocus event?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I designed one input text with label name.I used onfocus on text box it means i entering any name,some related names are displaying.Now my requirement is if i enter name it display one table under text-box that table contain ID or NO and NAME.So if i enter name,related names are display in table.I'm using bootstarp and Jquery. 
It is possible or not?

HTML:

```
 <div class="control-group ui-widget" > 
<label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label> 
<input id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
 </div>
```

Jquery:

```
    $("#name").autocomplete({ 
     source: name_list, 
      autoFocus: true,
     select: function (event, ui) { 
       ID = ui.item.id; 
     }
  });
 $("#name").focusout(function () {
 var nam = $("#name").val();
 var is = jQuery.inArray(nam, name_List);
 if (is < 0) {
 $("#name").val('');
 } 
});
```

Comment: of course possible. But u have to show ur code.

Comment: @Rahman:I designed only label and textbox only.i searched in google example code.

Comment: no problem. share that.

Comment: <div class="control-group ui-widget" >
    <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
</div>

Comment: $("#name").autocomplete({
        source: name_list,
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            ID = item.id;
        }
});

$("#name").focusout(function () {
    var nam = $("#name").val();
    var is = jQuery.inArray(nam, name_List);
    if (is < 0) {
    $("#name").val('');
    }
});

Comment: please put all code in question.update the question

Answer (score 0):

Parse response and construct table structure.

```
function (response) 
         {
           var trHTML = '';
           for(int i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
                trHTML += '<tr><td>' + response[i].ID+
                          '</td><td>' + response[i].Name +
                          '</td></tr>';
               }
           $('#result_table').append(trHTML);
           $('#result_table').show();
         }
```